# backbone rendering cascade views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cascade, html-rendering

I'm working on a backbone application that cascades views. There's one root view which creates its child views inside its `initialize` method and call child view rendering inside its own `render`. It may look like the following:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    console.log('body');
    this.template = tpl({});
    this.headerView = new HeaderView(options);
    this.chartView = new ChartView(options);
    this.footerView = new FooterView(options);
},

render: function() {
    console.log("body");
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    this.headerView.setElement(this.$el.find('.header')).render();
    this.chartView.setElement(this.$el.find('.chart')).render();
    this.footerView.setElement(this.$el.find('.footer')).render();
    return this;
}
```

All child views go the same way - they render themselves inside their `render` method and call `render` on their children.

My question is: why does entire page display after the very last view has finished rendering? My page is pretty complicated and it takes 4 seconds to load and I've got a blank page in the meantime. I've got lots of console outputs where I clearly see, that some of the views have already rendered.

I don't understand why such big amounts of HTML are not displayed on the fly. And I don't want it to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your root view is not yet attached to the dom.

You instantiate the root view, that will created an own `el` element that is not attached anywhere in the dom (this is legal). You then start rendering child views, that get appended to the root view... but still the root element is missing, so nothing gets displayed on screen. If these views are super complex, this process will take some time. When everything is done, you return from your root `render` function and the root `el` is finally attached to the dom, displaying everything.

To solve this, you can have the rendering of the subview happening after the root `el` has been attached to the dom (then you will see each piece incrementally). I am not saying that this approach is better, just that is a way to solve this performance issue.

One of the approaches could look something like:

```
RootView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // your initialize is here

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    },

    createHeaderView: function() {
        this.$el.find('.header').append(this.headerView.render().el);
    }

});

var root = new RootView()
$('body').append(root.render().el)
root.createHeaderView()
....
```

Here you notice that tha root `el` is attached to the dom *before* the subviews are rendered. This will make them appear incrementally.

Comment: could you please provide any snippet of example code so that I can understand what you mean by "rendering of the subview happening after the root el has been attached to the dom"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way - when exactly is the view `el` attached to DOM? Is it during `return this;`? Which lines of code are responsible for that?

Comment: Yes, I will add a snippet to my answer. To answer this question, yes, the root `el` is attached when `render` returns. `this` will be the View object so the code that instantiated the root view (Router? Main script?) will do something like `$('body').append(new RootView().render().el)`